# Check if record exist in Rest API?

Tags: php, mysql, api, rest, pdo

I'm writing my Rest API, and I have a doubt regarding the methods of `INSERT / UPDATE / DELETE`. In particular before performing any of the above methods I want to check if the record passed in the URI exists as:

```
endpoints/api/user/{id}
```

now my idea would be to place everything in the layer that I created by extending the PDO functions with such a method:

```
public function getWhere($table, $where)
{
    return $this->exec("SELECT * FROM $table WHERE $where");
}
```

And back appropriately `true` or `false` if the record has been found or not. But I wonder if this method is safe against `sql injection`. I also wonder if there is some other way to see if the record exists before update it or add it. I think my API will become something like a hundred models, so I need an efficient solution to be used in any model with ease.

Comment: Never pass user input directly to SQL query. Use prepared statements.

Comment: @RomanNazarkin Ok, and other hint for the method that check if the method exist on the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't extend the PDO classes with your own methods thinking it will help. It does not, please read [Your first database wrapper's childhood diseases](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/common_mistakes).

Use normal prepared statements to get a row for a specific id like:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT columns FROM users WHERE id = ?');
/* work with $stmt */
```

Comment: thanks for the suggest. I've removed the own method, just one thing: If I understand good your answer I need to execute in each model this method where I need it. It's right?